# Google Place autocomplete: prioritize by "types" establishment without forbidding address

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I'm creating a service to help users save establishments using Google Autocomplete API.

I'm using `type={'establishment'}` options to filter autocomplete results to show only establishments in order to speed-up the search process.

> For instance when typing "bo" autocomplete will suggest "Bowler club" instead of "Boise, Idaho, États-Unis".

**Problem**: with that option, autocomplete does not allow users to enter an address which is a serious friction for me.

**Question:** Is there a way to ask autocomplete to prioritize `establishment` results, without forbidding users to enter an address ?

**Update** (after MrUpsidown comment): Google Place Autocomplete do forbid the use of another `type` when using `type={'establishment'}` (see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/supported_types#table3) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#constrain-place-types)), so I'm looking for alternative solutions.

Note: I don't want to ask users' location.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/supported_types#table3

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, I added it to the post

Comment: I am confused at the docs now. It says *Only a single type from Table 3 is allowed in the request.* but calling `getPlacePredictions` from the AutocompleteService class with `geocode` and `establishment` (from Table 3) seems to work just fine... http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/dmwv1t4e/ and the docs from the [web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#types) mentions that you can *safely mix `geocode` and `establishment`* and I believe this was also mentioned in the JS API docs some time ago. Maybe it's a mistake.

Comment: it seems to be an exception indeed, moreover because type `geocode` is also present in Table 2 (they say Table 3 types cannot be mixed with Tables 1 and Table 2 types either)

Comment: But mixing `geocode` and `establishment` is not a solution either : autocomplete does not show establishments results first (you can try entering "boul" in your jsfiddle with & without the type `geocode`)

Comment: TBH, documentation is unclear. Table 2 is supposed to be only types **returned** in the response and not part of a request. I have asked google for clarification: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/255493667

Comment: *autocomplete does not show establishments results first* - nope, that's for sure. The only option I can think of would be to use the AutocompleteService class and do 2 separate calls to the API (1 for establishments and 1 for geocodes) and then combine the 2 responses results in the order you wish. Note that this will have a cost (2 calls to the API for 1 single client request).

Comment: Thank you for filling a req for clarification, and I believe your last comment is the only way to do this. Feel free to add this as an answer and I'd gladly check it.